# How to get this makefile to work correctly?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, centos

I cannot seem to get a makefile to run correctly. I am following an online Linux tutorial to compile C libraries. Just looking for the reasons why this will not run correctly. I get:

```
make: libsimple_math.a: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127.
```

- [source material](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/rute/node25.html)
- [link to files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uovBv4PqxWG-L7n83dDqWlGnFVqT0Bvb?usp=sharing)

`commands rUN:`

```
gcc -Wall -c simple_math_sqrt.c
gcc -Wall -c simple_math_pow.c
ar libsimple_math.a simple_math_sqrt.o simple_math_pow.o
ranlib libsimple_math.a
gcc -Wall -c mytest.c
gcc -o mytest mytest.o -L. -lsimple_math
```

Error received:

```
[root@]# make
libsimple_math.a mytest
make: libsimple_math.a: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

The makefile:

```
# Comments start with a # (hash) character like shell scripts.
# Makefile to build libsimple_math.a and mytest program.
# Paul Sheer <psheer@cranzgot.co.za> Sun Mar 19 15:56:08 2000

OBJS    = simple_math_sqrt.o simple_math_pow.o
LIBNAME = simple_math
CFLAGS  = -Wall

all:
        lib$(LIBNAME).a mytest

mytest:
        cp mytest /bin/mytest
        lib$(LIBNAME).a mytest.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ mytest.o -L. -l${LIBNAME}

lib$(LIBNAME).a:
        $(OBJS)
        rm -f $@
        ar rc $@ $(OBJS)
        ranlib $@

.c.o:
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -c -o $*.o $<

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.a mytest
```

Comment: Why did you not put `all:` and `lib$(LIBNAME).a mytest` on the same line, like in the example?

Comment: There might be an issue with: `ar libsimple_math.a simple_math_sqrt.o simple_math_pow.o`. I think you need an operation [just as you do in your Makefile] (e.g.) `ar crv libsimple_math.a simple_math_sqrt.o simple_math_pow.o`

Comment: its not it just copied over incorrectly. ill add picture of the cat make file.

Comment: i went back and edited "chetah" i was having errors before and my buddy who works in c++ told me the file had to be that way. it started to work after we did that.... i just changed it back to the way the example has it and now it works!! thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You problem is in the stanza:

```
mytest:
        cp mytest /bin/mytest
        lib$(LIBNAME).a mytest.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ mytest.o -L. -l${LIBNAME}
```

The second command line tries to execute the library as a command, and (mercifully), it fails.  It looks as though you might need:

```
mytest: lib$(LIBNAME).a mytest.o
        cp mytest /bin/mytest
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ mytest.o -L. -l${LIBNAME}
```

I'm not sure why you're copying `mytest` to `/bin` at all.  If that succeeds, it implies you must be running as `root` — don't!  It's too easy to make mistakes.  Alternatively: the permissions on `/bin` are broken — fix them (`chmod 755 /bin`).  And you should normally build the command before copying the new version to the target directory, rather than copying the old version to the target directory and then creating a new version.

I would create a macro for the library file name:

```
LIBFILE = lib${LIBNAME}.a
```

and then use that to identify the library file name.

You also have a similar problem (with a similar fix) at:

```
lib$(LIBNAME).a:
        $(OBJS)
        rm -f $@
        ar rc $@ $(OBJS)
        ranlib $@
```

Fix:

```
lib$(LIBNAME).a: $(OBJS)
        rm -f $@
        ar rc $@ $(OBJS)
        ranlib $@
```

or

```
$(LIBFILE): $(OBJS)
        rm -f $@
        ar rc $@ $(OBJS)
        ranlib $@
```

NB: I have not tried creating or running the `makefile` as outlined in the question or with the fixes suggested in this answer.  There could be other problems lurking unspotted.